# Find an upper bound for a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

How can I show that the following is true?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}} < 3$$

I just need this series to be between 1 and 3 so that I can conclude some result. I have found the appropriate lower bound series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2}} =\frac{\pi^2}{6}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}},$$ but am struggling to find an upper one. Could somebody lend me a hand, please?

Comment: if we have $f(x) > 0$ but $f'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  f(j) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  f(x) \; dx   $$

Comment: yeah, that works but needs $ 1 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{3/2}}$   and $ 1 + \int_1^\infty x^{-3/2}  dx $

Comment: Wow, that's such a good result. It works perfectly. Where can I read more about it?, you see, I'd like to know how this is derived.

Comment: We did that in high school.  That calculus book had the (simple) pictures for this. Let me see if I can find anything contemporary. We used Agnew, I have a pdf, maybe

Comment: To derive it, simply draw the pictures (the integrals are areas under a curve, while the sum is the area of a set of consecutive rectangles of width $1$ with one upper corner on the curve). These are left- and right-hand Riemann sum approximations to integrals of monotone functions.

Comment: Still, all above has been very helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: I drew a new picture  and posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant of the approaches presented so far is given by the Hermite-Hadamard inequality. $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence

$$ I(n)=2-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}=\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}} $$
fulfills
$$ I(n)\leq \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\right)+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}} $$
such that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}} \geq \frac{5}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right). \tag{LowerBound}$$
On the other hand if we consider
$$ J(n) = \int_{3/2}^{n+1/2}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}}= \sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}-\frac{4}{\sqrt{4n+2}}$$
we have
$$ J(n) \geq \sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}} $$
hence
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}\leq \color{red}{1+\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}} < 3.\tag{UpperBound} $$
This bound is pretty sharp: the actual difference between $\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$ and $1+\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}$ is just a bit greater than $0.02$.

Answer (score 5):

I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that does not require knowledge of integrals.  To that end we proceed.

First we can evaluate the telescoping series

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(k^{-1/2}-(k+1)^{-1/2}\right)=1\tag1$$

Next, we can rewrite $(1)$ as

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^{1/2}(k+1)^{1/2}\left(k^{1/2}+(k+1)^{1/2}\right)}=1\tag 2$$

Clearly we have from $(2)$

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac1{2k^{3/2}} < 1$$

from which we arrive at the coveted inequality

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^{3/2}}<3$$

And we are done.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer! I tried to find a telescoping series, too. But, clearly I failed!

Comment: (+1) my answer is along the same lines, but if we use this method for the lower bound as well, we get a better bound than $\frac{\pi^2}6$.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you for the +1.  And yes, we do indeed get a better lower bound with this approach.

Answer (score 4):

Working along the same lines as Mark Viola's answer, we can get upper and lower bounds.

Combining fractions, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac2{\sqrt{k}}-\frac2{\sqrt{k+1}}
&=2\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{k(k+1)}\left(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}\right)}\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Replacing $k$ with $k+1$ in $\text{(1b)}$, we get a lower bound. Replacing $k+1$ with $k$ in $\text{(1b)}$, we get an upper bound.
$$
\frac1{(k+1)\sqrt{k+1}}\le\frac2{\sqrt{k}}-\frac2{\sqrt{k+1}}\le\frac1{k\sqrt{k}}\tag2
$$
Summing in $k$ gives
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k\sqrt{k}}\le2\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k\sqrt{k}}\tag3
$$
Adding $1$ to the left inequality yields
$$
2\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k\sqrt{k}}\le3\tag4
$$

---

**Motivation**

The motivation for using $\frac2{\sqrt{k}}$ is because
$$
\int_k^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{x}}=\frac2{\sqrt{k}}\tag5
$$
Thus,
$$
\int_k^{k+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{x}}=\frac2{\sqrt{k}}-\frac2{\sqrt{k+1}}\tag6
$$
and from $(6)$, we see that
$$
\frac1{(k+1)\sqrt{k+1}}\le\int_k^{k+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{x}}\le\frac1{k\sqrt{k}}\tag7
$$
Putting together $(6)$ and $(7)$, we get $(2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Drew a new one. There is an incorrect $a-1$  on the lower left.

If we have $f(x) > 0$ but $f'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{k=a}^b \;  f(k) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  f(x) \; dx   $$

This has $f(x) > 0$   and $f'(x) < 0.$  The drawing shows an upper bound for the sum.

[image]

Comment: That is very nice, but I think it would be even nicer if you could add a sentence or two to make it into an actual answer.